# malicious files

Tags: terminal-server, malware

can virus's/spyware/malware/trojans/worms get on your remote desktop/terminal services servers from a local machine?

Answer (score 1):

If you have mapped local drives in your remote desktop session, yes, they could.

Comment: ok they are not, i need not worry any more